# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.push') react native , when i am trying to navigate from one page to another

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Here is the sample code , i am trying react-native-navigation

> i used **react-native init navigate** to start the project
>   and afterwards i installed
>
> **yarn add react-native-navigation@latest**

the code run perfect for first screen , but as i am making a call to showNextScreen function it throws the error

***undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push') react native***

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View
    } from 'react-native';
    import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
    import firstPage  from './app/components/firstPage';
    export default class navigate extends Component {
    //function to move to next screen
      showNextScreen = () =>{
        this.props.navigator.push({
          screen: 'firstPage',
          title: 'firstScreen'
        })
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              To get started, edit index.android.js
            </Text>
            <Text onPress={this.showNextScreen.bind(this)} 
            style={styles.instructions}>
              Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
              Shake or press menu button for dev menu
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('navigate', () => navigate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using React Native Navigation, you have to bootstrap your app differently than how it's done originally. Native Navigation doesn't use the registerComponent setup since it's a native navigator.

The steps to fully setting up are listed in their docs https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage

Comment: so is it compulsory to make my application in a tabbed view ?, as per your reference link

Comment: @devanshsadhotra You have two ways to start. 

TabBased - https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=starttabbasedappparams

SingleScreen - https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=startsinglescreenappparams